# Suppress output to stderr in matlab

Tags: matlab, logging, stderr

I'm trying to suppress output from a code section in a script (namely the network initialization from a Caffe network). I've tried wrapping the corresponding bit of code in an `evalc` command

```
[suppressed_output, var_output] = evalc('someFunction(input)');
```

But this doesn't work. I've still got loads of lines of (non-error) output from the network initialization that are clogging my logs (amidst all the wanted output printed via `fprintf('')` in the script). I think this happens because the corresponding function is writing to `STDERR` (instead of `STDOUT`?) - the first line it prints is this warning:

```
WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
```

... and then hundreds of lines of what it is doing follow, e.g.:

```
I0215 15:01:51.840272 28620 upgrade_proto.cpp:66] Attempting to upgrade input file specified using deprecated input fields: tmp-def.prototxt
I0215 15:01:51.840360 28620 upgrade_proto.cpp:69] Successfully upgraded file specified using deprecated input fields.
...
```

**Can I somehow suppress the output to `STDERR` (without messing with the function content)?** Ideally only locally for this specific function, since I'd still like to get potential error messages.

In case it is relevant:
I call `myScript` via matlab command line and its output written to a log (`mlexec.log`) with `tee`:

```
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -display :1 -r "try, myScript; catch e, disp(getReport(e)), end, quit force" 2>&1| tee mlexec.log
```

Comment: I think the syntax is `2>NUL`

Comment: @Rotem wow, that actually pointed right to the flaw. `2>&1` streamed the `STDERR` output right to `STDOUT` which I needed for debugging waaay back. Streaming `STDERR` (`2`) to Nirvana `2>NUL` or a different log file (`2>mlexec.stderr.log`) solves the problem. Thank you - you want post to this as an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Glad I could help... You allowed to post it as an answer if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is, that in the matlab command line call, the output from `STDERR` is streamed to `STDOUT` by this "command": `2>&1`. Since the .cpp file seems to stream its output to `STDERR` (according to the Warning), it will be forwarded to `STDOUT` and eventually the log.

Streaming `STDERR` (2) to Nirvana with `2>NUL` or a different log file (e.g. `2>mlexec.stderr.log`) solves the problem.

Answer (score -2):

I wanted to post this in a comment but it said I had to have 50 reputation (I have 49 now...)

I think [this is what you're looking for](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/suppress-warnings.html)
**EDIT/UPDATE:**

One thing you can do is enclose a section of your code with warning on/off statements as follows:

```
warning('off','all')
%your code here
warning('on','all')
```

This should stop any warnings being output to `stderr` from that section. I personally do not recommend this, it's good to know what you're doing that the MATLAB runtime does not like.

Comment: This is a link only answer, which are generally discouraged (links break, etc.). Please expand on the content at the link as pertains to the question or delete this.

Comment: I apologize for the not very complete answer. I tried commenting but I haven't been around long enough to get the reputation to post comments on other people's posts. I hope this takes care of it @horchler :)

Comment: @sharif anani: Thanks for the suggestion and edit. I'm aware of the `warning('off','all')` option, but haven't tried it yet, as the problem is not the warning but all the other lines (that are written to STDERR). Still I gave it a try, but with no effect. Interestingly enough the cited warning doesn't disappear, too. I assume it is part of the text written to STDERR, originating not from Matlab but from the .cpp sources (and hence cannot be turned off by the Matlab command).